# Storage & Network device drivers source code for Nexus 6 and Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: android, driver, linux-device-driver, android-source, device-driver

For university research purposes, I am searching for a specific part of Nexus 6, and Samsung Galaxy S6 source code. Particularly, I am interested in "network" & "storage" driver source codes. I have visited developer resources for both [Samsung](http://opensource.samsung.com/reception/receptionSub.do?method=sub&sub=F&searchValue=sm-g92) (which are said to be open-sourced), and [Motorolla](http://www.motorola.com/us/Motorola-Developers/motorola-developers.html), but was unable to find the desired code.

I also have the pure Android source code on [this](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) website, but I guess the drivers for "network" & "storage" might be hardware-specific.

I am having a hard time locating "network" & "storage" drivers for the mentioned two devices. In case the code I am looking for is open-sourced, can anybody please let me know where they are located?

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/general/bounty-aosp-source-code-galaxy-s6g920-t3235453/post63605680#post63605680 and https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers

Comment: https://github.com/mythos234?tab=repositories

Comment: @AngelusMortis Thank you. I appreciate it if you could please point me to the Network and/or Storage driver source codes.

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that a specific model (Samsung Galaxy S6 for example) can have different components in different production batches. Devices produced months after an initial batch may contain different Wifi/Bluetooth/storage components with different drivers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the code for drivers(from kernel) of-

- Samsung Galaxy S6 - [Network](https://github.com/glewarne/S6-UniKernel/tree/b8c8acb57d3bafb704bb97e2bbd2222a5e7c05da/drivers/net) and [Storage](https://github.com/glewarne/S6-UniKernel/tree/b8c8acb57d3bafb704bb97e2bbd2222a5e7c05da/drivers/usb/storage).
- Nexus 6 - [Network](https://github.com/Elite-Kernels/elite_shamu/tree/2e500b56c8c845dbe66fffe2a5015c5e4c74ca80/drivers/net) and [Storage](https://github.com/Elite-Kernels/elite_shamu/tree/2e500b56c8c845dbe66fffe2a5015c5e4c74ca80/drivers/usb/storage)
- Nexus 6P - [Network](https://github.com/anarkia1976/AK-Angler/tree/android-msm-angler-3.10-marshmallow-dr/net) and [Storage](https://github.com/anarkia1976/AK-Angler/tree/android-msm-angler-3.10-marshmallow-dr/drivers/usb/storage)

But, as FunkSoulBrother pointed out, each batch of manufacturing and every model variation(Europe, US specific carrier models, International model etc.,) will have different drivers. As chances are internals also change. So, this can be a starting point for your research for sure :) Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you. I accepted your answer. One more question though: do you know where I can find the same codes for Nexus 6P?

Comment: The links to 6P dirvers are broken. Any idea where they have moved to?

Comment: @Campiador Checkout Nexus 6P branch [here](https://github.com/norbertc/nexus-kernel).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this site http://androidxref.com/.You can browse most of the android source code-Not very sure of specific drivers.